# jquery success/error callbacks not firing

Tags: jquery, callback

This seems to be a frequently encountered situation but none of the solutions suggested to the earlier problems seem to address mine! Neither the success nor the error callbacks are firing. However, the JSON data returned is accurate and all seems well on the server/firephp side as well. I've been staring at it for a few days now and would appreciate a hand!

First, my Javascript call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: global_siteurl+'myprog/get_my_data',
    data: "",
    type: 'post',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function () {   
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Failed");
    }
});
```

Now the server side php routine:

```
function get_my_data() {
    $output=array();
    $output['status']=1;
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

JSON ouput in Firebug:

```
status      1
```

What other info can I look at to debug this? Other calls very similar to this seem to be working just fine in my application so it has me flummoxed!

Mmiz

Answer (score 0):

Quick guess:

```
function get_my_data() {
    $output=array();
    $output['status']=1;
    return json_encode($output); <---
}
```